# gpg not working pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8 while decrypt inside a while loop

Tags: linux, bash

My gpg is working fine

```
gpg -c /home/abcd/test.text
```

Its asking my the password 2 times and works fine but it gave the error when I was trying

```
while IFS="," read -r rec_column1 rec_column2
do
gpg -c /home/abcd/test.txt
done < <(tail -n +1 list.csv)
```

any help

The error is

```
can't connect to `/root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
                                                   pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
```

Comment: Whatever "the error" is: how is this related to programming?

Comment: ``` pinentry-curses: no LC_CTYPE known - assuming UTF-8
``` this is the error a I mentioned in header/title

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for any important information

Comment: added Please have alook